# Vector of inherited classes

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector

I keep looking around fruitlessly for the solution to this,

I have a number of classes which inherit from one base class:

```
#ifndef navalVesselClass
#define navalVesselClass

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
class navalVessel
{

public:
    std::string Name_;
    std::string Type_;
    std::string OperatingCountry_;
    std::string Built_;
    std::string ServiceDate_;
    bool Active_;
    double Length_;
    double Displacement_;
    double Beam_;
    double Draft_;
    double Speed_;
    double Range_;


private:

};

#endif
```

and then, for instance a class that inherits it:

```
#ifndef destroyerClass
#define destroyerClass

#include "surfaceCombatant.h"
#include <string>




class destroyer: public surfaceCombatant
{
public: 
    enum class ArmamentPrimary { ANTIAIR, MISSILE };
    enum class ArmamentSecondary { TORPEDOS, MISSILE, ANTIAIR, ANTIGROUND };        
    ArmamentPrimary primaryArmament;
    ArmamentSecondary secondaryArmament;
private:

};



#endif
```

Now, When i want to STORE these objects in a vector i'm creating a vector as follows

```
std::vector<navalVessel *> shipFleet
```

Using that, i can store both, destroyers and other ships in this vector as pointers, HOWEVER once i try and retrieve them again, they are of course of the type 'navalVessel' and i cannot access any of the derived classes variables? e.g. primary weapon, i can only get access to the base class attributes.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you are looking for `dynamic_cast`?

Comment: I think you are looking for refactoring your design?

Comment: Also, we can read code. Can you please post code instead schematized versions of your classes?

Comment: That is correct, and for good reason. Unless you say that all naval vessels have a primary and secondary weapon (which I doubt is the case), you do not know if the element in the vector you are referring to has these methods.

Comment: @OMGtechy I presumed at first i could have used a dynamic cast? though i ran into 'must have a polymorphic class type'

Comment: You could cast the `Base*` to a `Derived*`, yes. However, you're better off trying to avoid this problem altogether by redesigning.

Comment: This kind of design problem shows the single biggest misconception about object oriented programming and I still don't know how to formulate a useful reply :(

Comment: @OMGtechy How can simply 'redesigning' two practically empty classes change the way i can store and retrieve them? is there perhaps a more 'recommended' method of storing inherited class data?

Comment: @xBroak it's not the classes, it's the way you store them that needs changing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your design is flawed and you won't be able to do this without enabling RTTI and using `dynamic_cast`.
But this is useless as your design would remain bad or getting even worse.

I would suggest reading on some OOP basics as you do not fully understand the implication of base classes and polymorphism.

The idea of a base class is to provide a common set of methods which results in different values depending upon implementation of a concrete type.

In your scenario your base class should provide a member to obtain a list of possible weapons and every concrete implementation would return their set of weapons. Ships without weapons would return an empty list, etc.

But again. You have deep flaws in your understanding of abstract classes in C++. It is absolutely necessary to provide at least a virtual destructor in your base class.

Comment: Great response, went back and setup the virtual destructor etc. i shall work my way backwards i suppose and think again.

Comment: With that said, i DID get it working with dynamic cast (my original problem)

Comment: @xBroak: some more things: It is a good idea to not violate the liskov substitution principle (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). Your classes should rely on accessor methods and not expose members publicly. Members are ALWAYS implementation detail and should not be exposed by the class directly. C++ allows to have members in `ìnterface` classes (which is basically an abstract class) but this often lead to non pure abstract classes being used as interface objects resulting in a higher coupling of caller and callee as changing inner implementation has outside effects.

Comment: So my base class should declare ALL of the variables, while the derived classes simply limit the returned dataset depending on what they are allowed to have? So base class has a list of all the weapons, destroyer returns x,y,z weapons that a destroyer can have FROM the base classes set?

Comment: @xBroak: No, your base class should provide the **common** set of methods which can be used regardless of what explicit type you have. Of course some situations simply require to knowing the explicit type. There are several techniques to obtain the proper type. One technique is RTTI (either compiler build-in or macro magic) to get the info what explicit type the pointer is and then cast (or dynamic_cast) it to it. Another way is a per-type static manager that stores a list of T-only instances which can then be asked if ptr is of type T (albeit it may be complex or cumbersome)

Answer (score 0):

Cast navalVessel* to pointer of whatever derived class the actual type is. Use a dynamic_cast.

Comment: Attempted that, hit the following: 'must have a polymorphic class type' from what i can tell, i need a 'virtual' function but not sure on the implementation?

Comment: @xBroak Your destructor should be virtual at least

Comment: Yes. BTW why have a vector of base pointers if there are no virtual functions.? What are you trying to achieve?